# SQL incorrect syntax 'Union'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

ı don' understand why give me this error.ı don't write union all like this error.Please give me solution. İf you want to result of this code,can ı write its.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME;

/* WHERE */

SET @StartDate = 

/* T0.TaxDate */

'';

/*SELECT FROM [dbo].[OINV] T1*/

DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME;

/* WHERE */

SET @EndDate = 

/* T1.TaxDate */

'';

/*SELECT FROM [dbo].[OINV] T2*/

DECLARE @OurOffice VARCHAR(MAX);

/* WHERE */

SET @OurOffice = 

/* T2.U_CFFIRMASI */ 

'';

IF(@StartDate = '')
    SET @StartDate =
(
    SELECT TOP 1 T0.TaxDate
    FROM OINV T0
    ORDER BY T0.TaxDate ASC
);
IF(@EndDate = '')
    SET @EndDate =
(
    SELECT TOP 1 T0.TaxDate
    FROM OINV T0
    ORDER BY T0.TaxDate DESC
);
DECLARE @MyTemp TABLE
(DatabaseName VARCHAR(MAX),
 RowNumber    INT
);
INSERT INTO @MyTemp
(RowNumber,
 DatabaseName
)
       SELECT RowNumber,
              DatabaseName
       FROM QUESINTERNATIONALCORP.dbo.GETVOLUMEQTYDATABASES();
DECLARE @loopLimit INT=
(
    SELECT TOP 1 RowNumber
    FROM @MyTemp
    ORDER BY RowNumber DESC
);
DECLARE @loopCounter INT= 1;
DECLARE @sqlInsertCommand NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sqlSingleCommand NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @myTempTableName NVARCHAR(80);
DECLARE @SystemCurr NVARCHAR(3);
DECLARE @MainCurr NVARCHAR(3);
DECLARE @myTempleTableRealName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SystemCurrSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @MainCurrSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @myTempleTableRealNameSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
WHILE(@loopCounter <= @loopLimit)
    BEGIN
        SET @myTempTableName =
(
    SELECT DatabaseName
    FROM @MyTemp
    WHERE RowNumber = @loopCounter
);
        SET @SystemCurrSql = N'SELECT @SystemCurrOut = 
    SysCurrncy
    FROM '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OADM';
        SET @MainCurrSql = N'SELECT @MainCurrOut = 
    MainCurncy
    FROM '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OADM';
        SET @myTempleTableRealNameSQL = N'SELECT @MainNameOut = 
    CompnyName
    FROM '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OADM';
        EXECUTE sp_executesql
                @SystemCurrSql,
                N'@SystemCurrOut NVARCHAR(3) OUTPUT',
                @SystemCurrOut = @SystemCurr OUTPUT;
        EXECUTE sp_executesql
                @MainCurrSql,
                N'@MainCurrOut NVARCHAR(3) OUTPUT',
                @MainCurrOut = @MainCurr OUTPUT;
        EXECUTE sp_executesql
                @myTempleTableRealNameSQL,
                N'@MainNameOut NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
                @MainNameOut = @myTempleTableRealName OUTPUT;
        SET @sqlSingleCommand = '

(SELECT RESULT.Country,
       RESULT.[Our Office],
       RESULT.[Inv.Company],
       RESULT.[Team Leader],
       RESULT.[Trade/Comm.],
       RESULT.[Inv. Date],
       RESULT.Customer,
       RESULT.Department,
       RESULT.[Cust.Inv.No],
      RESULT.SoNum,
      RESULT.PONum,
       RESULT.[Mfr. Name],
       RESULT.[Mfr.Inv.No],
       RESULT.Terms,
       RESULT.[Due Date],
       RESULT.[Sales(Original)],
       RESULT.[Currency(S)],
       RESULT.[Cost of Sales(Original)],
       RESULT.[Currency(COS)],
       RESULT.[Sales(Original)] - RESULT.[Cost of Sales(Original)] AS [Gross Profit],
       CAST(CAST(((RESULT.[Sales(Original)] - RESULT.[Cost of Sales(Original)]) / (CASE
                                                                                       WHEN RESULT.[Sales(Original)] = 0
                                                                                       THEN 1
                                                                                       ELSE RESULT.[Sales(Original)]
                                                                                   END)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19, 2)) AS NVARCHAR)+[%] AS [Margin %],
       RESULT.SOQuantity,
       RESULT.POQuantity,
       RESULT.ARQuantity,
       RESULT.APQuantity,
       RESULT.[Sales(Reporting)],
       RESULT.[Cost of Sales(Reporting)],
       RESULT.[Sales(Reporting)] - RESULT.[Cost of Sales(Reporting)] AS [Gross Profit],
       CAST(CAST(((RESULT.[Sales(Reporting)] - RESULT.[Cost of Sales(Reporting)]) / (CASE
                                                                                    WHEN RESULT.[Sales(Reporting)] = 0
                                                                                    THEN 1
                                                                                    ELSE RESULT.[Sales(Reporting)]
                                                                                END)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(19, 2)) AS NVARCHAR)+[%] AS [Margin %],
       RESULT.DocRate,
       RESULT.Month,
       RESULT.Year,
       RESULT.Week
FROM
(
    SELECT T0.U_URETIMULKESI AS [Country],
           T0.U_CFFIRMASI AS [Our Office],
(
    SELECT A0.CompnyName
    FROM '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OADM A0
) AS [Inv.Company],
           T8.Name AS [Team Leader],
           T0.U_ARGNS_OrderType AS [Trade/Comm.],
           T5.TaxDate AS [Inv. Date],
           T0.CardName AS [Customer],
           T9.U_ARGNS_LineCode AS [Department],
           T5.U_FATNO AS [Cust.Inv.No],
           T3.CardName AS [Mfr. Name],
           T11.U_FATNO AS [Mfr.Inv.No],
           T12.PymntGroup AS [Terms],
           T5.DocRate,
           T5.DocDueDate AS [Due Date],
           ((CASE
                 WHEN T4.Currency =
(
    SELECT A0.MainCurncy
    FROM '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OADM A0
)
                 THEN T4.LineTotal
                 WHEN T4.Currency =
(
    SELECT A0.SysCurrncy
    FROM '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OADM A0
)
                 THEN T4.TotalSumSy
                 ELSE T4.TotalFrgn
             END) * (1 - T0.DiscPrcnt)) AS [Sales(Original)],
           T4.Currency AS [Currency(S)],
           (CASE
                WHEN T6.Currency =
(
    SELECT A0.MainCurncy
    FROM '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OADM A0
)
                THEN T6.OpenSum
                WHEN T6.Currency =
(
    SELECT A0.SysCurrncy
    FROM '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OADM A0
)
                THEN T6.OpenSumSys
                ELSE T6.OpenSumFC
            END) AS [Cost of Sales(Original)],
           T6.Currency AS [Currency(COS)],
           T1.Quantity AS [SOQuantity],
           T2.Quantity AS [POQuantity],
           T4.Quantity AS [ARQuantity],
           T6.Quantity AS [APQuantity],
           T6.OpenSumSys AS [Cost of Sales(Reporting)],
           T4.OpenSumSys AS [Sales(Reporting)],
           MONTH(T5.TaxDate) AS [Month],
           YEAR(T5.TaxDate) AS [Year],
           DATEPART(wk, T5.TaxDate) AS [Week],
         T0.DocEntry as [SoNum],
         T3.DocEntry as [PoNum]
    FROM '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.ORDR T0
         INNER JOIN '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.RDR1 T1 ON T1.DocEntry = T0.DocEntry
         INNER JOIN '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.POR1 T2 ON T2.BaseEntry = T1.DocEntry
                               AND T2.BaseLine = T1.LineNum
                               AND T2.BaseType = T1.ObjType
         INNER JOIN '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OPOR T3 ON T3.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry
         INNER JOIN '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.INV1 T4 ON T4.BaseEntry = T1.DocEntry
                               AND T4.BaseLine = T1.LineNum
                               AND T4.BaseType = T1.ObjType
         INNER JOIN '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OINV T5 ON T5.DocEntry = T4.DocEntry
         LEFT JOIN '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.PCH1 T6 ON T6.BaseEntry = T2.DocEntry
                               AND T6.BaseLine = T2.LineNum
                               AND T6.BaseType = T2.ObjType
         LEFT JOIN '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OPCH T11 ON T11.DocEntry = T6.DocEntry
         LEFT JOIN '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OHEM T7 ON T7.empID = T0.OwnerCode
         LEFT JOIN '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OUDP T8 ON T8.Code = T7.dept
         LEFT JOIN '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.'+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OITM T9 ON T9.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode
         LEFT JOIN '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OUBR T10 ON T10.Code = T7.branch
         LEFT JOIN '+@myTempTableName+'.dbo.OCTG T12 ON T5.GroupNum = T12.GroupNum
    WHERE T0.Canceled = ''N''
          AND T3.CANCELED = ''N''
          AND T5.CANCELED = ''N''
      AND T5.TaxDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
      AND (T5.U_CFFIRMASI = @OurOffice
           OR @OurOffice = '''')
) AS RESULT ) ';
 IF(@loopCounter = 1)
            BEGIN
                SET @sqlInsertCommand = @sqlSingleCommand;
            END;
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @sqlInsertCommand = @sqlInsertCommand+'UNION ALL '+@sqlSingleCommand;
                select @sqlInsertCommand
            END;
        SET @loopCounter = @loopCounter + 1;
    END;

EXECUTE sp_executesql
        @sqlInsertCommand;
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 103 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'UNION'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 408 Incorrect syntax near
>   'Year'.

Comment: `PRINT @YourDynamicSQLVariable;` is your best friend. Don't try to debug the dynamic SQL generator, debug the generated SQL, and then propagate that to the generator. We can't run the SQL you've, so we can't see what the dynamic SQL being run is either. If you're unable to debug the generated SQL, post that as well.

Comment: What line is line 103 and 408?

Comment: Also, `QUOTENAME` is another best friend of your when using Dynamic SQL.

Comment: Try with the space before union as `@sqlInsertCommand+' UNION ALL '+@sqlSingleCommand;`

Comment: I don't think you're setting `@sqlInsertCommant` before you use it

Comment: I don't think you're setting @sqlInsertCommant before you use it.İts not working

Comment: Is there a way to increase the number of nvarchar (max) 'n characters

Comment: `nvarchar(MAX)` can store up the 2GB of characters. For an `nvarchar` that's `1,073,741,824`. If you have a dynamic query that is longer than that you're doing something wrong (in fact, having a query anywhere near that length is ridiculous).

Comment: To put that into perspective, War & Peace has 587,287 words in it. Even if the average word length was 10 characters (including punctuation such as whitespace, commas, periods, etc), then the total character count would be just shy of 6M characters. That's less than 0.6% of the total storage size in a `nvarchar(MAX)`. You could easily fit another 150 copies of it in the same field. An `nvarchar(MAX)` is large enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a world of problems here:

1. you seem to have place holders for @StartDate, @EndDate and @OurOffice, but I cannot see that you have declared them as parameters when passing in to sp_executesql? (Potentially the cause of your first error).
2. you are concatenating an nvarchar(80) (@myTempTableName) in to an nvarchar(max). This will cause an implicit conversion of @sqlSingleCommand to an 8000 byte string (4000 characters for nvarchar I believe?) See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/varcharmax-field-cutting-off-data-after-8000-characters) for an example of this behaviour. (likely to be the cause of your second error).
3. Point 2 is also likely to be applicable when attempting to generate @sqlInsertCommand.
4. @OurOffice is a varchar(max), which I think will again cause an implicit conversion when generating the sql command, as you are adding this to a variable of nvarchar(max). Similar question and example [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b26fb632-86c1-490c-bab9-9dcc8e2e2931/nvarchar-truncates-when-concatenating-varchar-strings-why?forum=transactsql)

Solutions:

1. Ensure all your variables are declared appropriately. (i.e. nvarchar).
2. You need to pass in @StartDate, @EndDate and @OurOffice in to your sp_executesql call.

Optional:

If you are not parsing user input in to your code, you may be able to get away with using EXEC(@sqlcommmand) instead of EXEC sp_executesql, as EXEC has no limit on query size, as it is not parameterised (discussed [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1471602-1633-1.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

I think the `@sqlInsertCommand` variable is too small.

Try to separate your query into several variables and change

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql
        @sqlInsertCommand;
```

to

```
EXEC('EXEC sp_executesql N''' + @sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3 + @sql4 + '''')
```

P.S. 
It is not a good idea to write such long, dynamic queries. 
However, I understand that somewhere, someone may require such a query.